# Move tag to other commit

Tags: pygit2

While I can imagine to e.g. delete the tag via `Reference.delete` and then to recreate it anew (on the other commit), I wonder what the "official" way of moving a tag in pygit2 is.

Answer (score 0):

The race-free way to change that a reference points to is by setting its target field.

```
ref.target = tag.id
```

will make sure it updates the reference, removing a possible race condition with a cleanup process.